# Bootstrap / JQuery, space key not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form with some inputs text.
All keys works fine in text inputs except the spacebar key.
When I alert the keyCode it alert 32 but nothing append in the field.

I'm using JQuery 1.10.2, JQeryUI 1.9.2 and twitter bootstrap.

As a side note, the whole form is rendered in ajax with xajax library (http://www.xajax-project.org/)

Nothing fancy about the HTML :

```
<div class="span6">
    <div id="dJob_Title" class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Job title</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="Job_title" id="Job_title" class="span12" placeholder="Job title..." value="'.$Job_title.'">                                
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.
(sorry for my very bad English).

Comment: What's supposed to happen in the field? show more of you code

Comment: can u past your code in this http://jsfiddle.net/fFxj5/

Comment: Well... it will need "a lot of code to paste" to reproduce a think, but go to http://lgi-consulting.org/jobboard/index.php and try to enter spaces in the keywords input field in the right sidebar. between as i never tryied before on this page, sounds like it's the image slider at the bottom who is "capturing" the space key event. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Problem I think is you havent closed your input tag or check if all html tags are well formatted

```
<input type="text" name="Job_title" id="Job_title" class="span12" placeholder="Job title..." value="'.$Job_title.'">                                


</input>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but still no luck with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i finaly found out the mistake.
It's a js for image slider (fadeSlideShow.js) 
As it's instantiate in index.php (and 90% of the site is rendered via ajax in a div in index.php) even if i don't see it, it still capturing the space event (wich is autoplay)

i just commented this in the js :

```
else if(e.which==32){
    if(intval){stopAutoplay();}
    else{autoplay();}
return false;
}
```

and all is fine !

Thank you all for your response/reactivity and the waste of your time for something i have should seen before.